# Numpy 3d array delete first entry from every row

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Let's say I have a 3d Numpy array:

```
array([[[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [0, 2, 5]]])
```

Is it possible to remove the first entry from all the rows (those inner most rows). In this case the 0 would be deleted in each row.

Giving us the following output:

```
[[[1, 2],
  [1, 2],
  [2, 5]]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x
array([[[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [0, 2, 5]]])

x.shape
# (1, 3, 3)
```

You can use `Ellipsis` (`...`) to select across all the outermost axes, and slice out the first value from each row with `1:`.

```
x[..., 1:]    
array([[[1, 2],
        [1, 2],
        [2, 5]]])

x[..., 1:].shape
# (1, 3, 2)
```

Comment: Can you explain this syntax?

Comment: @JamesMitchell `...` means the other axes are not operated on in any way. The `1:` indicates to slice the last column in the innermost axis.

Answer (score 1):

To complement @coldspeed's response), [slicing in `numpy` is very powerful and can be done in a variety of ways including with the colon operator `:` in the index](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.16.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html), that is

```
print(x[:,:,1:])
# array([[[1, 2],
#         [1, 2],
#         [2, 5]]])
```

is equivalent to the established use of the ellipsis.